# Regex to match all paths which are not in a specific directory

Tags: regex, regex-negation

**Goal**: I want to match all paths which are NOT in `elasticmapreduce/j-abc123/node/i-abc123/applications` directory

Following are a set of possible paths:

```
elasticmapreduce/j-abc123/node/i-abc123/applications/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-proxyserver-ip.log.2020-05-07-00.gz
elasticmapreduce/j-abc123/node/i-abc123/applications/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-timelineserver-ip.out.gz
elasticmapreduce/j-abc123/node/i-abc123/applications/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-proxyserver-ip.log.gz
elasticmapreduce/j-abc123/node/i-abc123/applications/hive/user/hive/hive.log.2020-05-07.gz
elasticmapreduce/j-abc123/node/i-abc123/applications
elasticmapreduce/j-abc123/node/i-abc123/bootstrap-actions/master.log.2020-05-07-00.gz
elasticmapreduce/j-abc123/node/i-abc123/bootstrap-actions
elasticmapreduce/j-abc123/node/i-abc123/daemons/instance-state/instance-state.log-2020-05-08-13-30.gz
elasticmapreduce/j-abc123/node/i-abc123/daemons/setup-dns.log.gz
elasticmapreduce/j-abc123/node/i-abc123/provision-node/abc123/stderr.gz
elasticmapreduce/j-abc123/node/i-abc123/provision-node/apps-phase/0/abc123/stderr.gz
elasticmapreduce/j-abc123/node/i-abc123/provision-node/reports/0/abc123/ip.ec2.internal/201805270306.yaml.gz
elasticmapreduce/j-abc123/node/i-abc123/setup-devices/setup_var_log_dir.log.gz
```

Following regex matches all paths containing `elasticmapreduce/j-abc123/node/i-abc123/applications`:

```
^elasticmapreduce\/j-.*\/node\/i-.*\/(applications(\/.*)*)$
```

I want to match all paths which were NOT matched by above regex pattern.

**Why doesn't the following regex do this?**

```
^elasticmapreduce\/j-.*\/node\/i-.*\/(?!(applications(\/.*)*))$
```

PS, I use https://regex101.com/ to test regex patterns.

Comment: Do you mean like this? `^elasticmapreduce\/j-[^\/]+\/node\/i-[^\/]+\/(?!applications)[^\/]*(?:\/.*)?$` https://regex101.com/r/fUUrlX/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern that you tried does not work as you intended, as it will match until the last occurrence of a `/` and then has to fulfill this part `(?!(applications(\/.*)*))$`

The part asserts what is directly to the right is not `applications` followed by 0 or more repetitions of `/` followed by any char. Then assert the end of the string.

It starts backtracking and can not match in any of the examples.

I think it shows better when you omit the `$` and see where the match ends:

https://regex101.com/r/aXV8vO/1

---

As you are not matching a part that contains a a forward slash after `j-` and `i-`, you could make use of a negated character class instead `[^\/]+` matching any char except a forward slash.

Then use the negative lookahead `\/(?!applications\b)` right after matching the forward slash.

```
^elasticmapreduce\/j-[^\/]+\/node\/i-[^\/]+\/(?!applications\b)[^\/]*(?:\/.*)?$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lAHb6u/1)

**Note** If you don't want to cross newlines, you could use `[^\/\r\n]+` instead.